# How to make a special auto-subtractor?

Tags: javascript, subtraction

I want to make with JS, a subtraction which auto-subtract the biggest number from the smallest one... How to do so ? Thanks

Comment: at least post your numbers array

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Specifically **Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.**

Comment: with a list of numbers or just two numbers in variables?

Comment: @Racialz Just 2 numbers in an input field.

Comment: Hint: `max(a,b)-min(a,b)=|a-b|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HTML5, if you listen for the `oninput` event of two `<input type="number" />` fields, you can call `Math.abs()` on the difference between the two numbers, and it will update constantly.

Here's a small demo:

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("firstNum"),
    input2 = document.getElementById("secondNum"),
    output = document.getElementById("output");

input1.oninput = input2.oninput = function() {
  var num1 = parseInt(input1.value),
      num2 = parseInt(input2.value);
  output.innerHTML = Math.abs(num1 - num2);
};
```

```html
Input 1: <input type="number" value="0" id="firstNum" /><br>
Input 2: <input type="number" value="0" id="secondNum" /><br>
Output: <span id="output">0</span>
```

Comment: It doesn't work...

Comment: Whoops, it's working now.